# k-means clustering with efficient point lookup?

Tags: trees, binary-search-trees, clustering

What's an algorithm for $k$-means clustering, in particular an online algorithm (you can stream new points to it), such that once the size of the set of clusters $k$ becomes large, we can still efficiently lookup a point $p$ and classify it into a cluster ID (an integer)?

Obviously standard $k$-means alone is not sufficient.   Would putting the centroids of each cluster into a BSP or $k'$D-tree do the trick?  I used $k'$ there because that $k'$ has nothing to do with $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the classical $k$-means algorithm where you

- classify all points and then
- update the center of each cluster to be the average of all points of that cluster,

you could use the *sequential* variant of $k$-means:

```
centers = random(k)
while True:
    p = next_point(points)
    c = find_center(centers, p)
    c = c + a * (p - c)
```

`next_point` iterates all the points and maybe prefers new points (*online*) for example by using deque and putting new points front.

`find_center` classifies a point. This takes $O(k)$ naive and $O(\log k)$ using a spacial datastructure like a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search).

$a \in [0,1]$ says how much a center moves in the direction of the given point. Usually this is time dependent and gets lower with time, i.e. $a(t) = \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_2 t}$. Maybe one could boost the weight of new points though.

Comment: What is `c = c + a * (p - c)` doing?  What is `a`?  Also, why do you think that `find_center` can be done in $O(\log k)$ time?  I don't think that's true -- the running time depends on the dimension, and if the number of dimensions is large, it might be slow.

Comment: Explained `a` in answer, thanks. Runtime: k-d trees and similar datastructures can find the nearest neighbor `independently` of the dimension because they build a search tree where each node halfes the search space `along any dimension`. But you are right, I did not think too hard about _updating_ the position of a center in the tree. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Complexity) it's O(log k) where k is the number of points in the tree, not the dimension. But you may have to rebuild the tree from time to time to balance it.

Comment: I know Wikipedia says it is $O(\log k)$, but Wikipedia leaves out something very important: the dependence on the dimension.  In fact, the dependence on the dimension appears to be exponential in the number of dimensions, so the running time is more akin to $O((\log k)^d)$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions.  Empirically, my experience is that once $d$ starts getting large, k-d trees aren't much faster than naive linear search through all the points.